# BigTable data load pattern optimization

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I’m loading data into a BigTable cluster (currently a developer instance). I’m using the c++ client to put data and I see two different load patterns:

1. Issue one single row mutation at time using the Apply method of the Table class
2. Issue multiple mutations at time using the BulkApply method of the Table class

I expect #2 to be more efficient, at least in term of network usage, but I don’t know if there are some other optimizations on the BigTable side that would allow better performances (eg better compression, less CPU/IO pressure) compared to option #1.

Definitely the question is: is it worth to add complexity to a BigTable client in order to perform bulk mutations or should I fire every mutation immediately and forget about any other client side optimization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you point out, there are network savings when using BulkApply. There is also savings in terms of cpu in the client, less request/response work, and in the Bigtable serverm mutations going to the same row or contiguous row range will be applied in bulk.

These savings will depend quite a bit on the distribution of data being inserted, and the complexity added also depends on how your application is designed. The c++ client offers a BulkApply method that should make it easy:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/blob/master/google/cloud/bigtable/table_bulk_apply_test.cc#L59

For inserting large amounts of data, Cloud Bigtable users find that bulk apply is worth it due to the node cpu savings and more insertion throughput.

Comment: You should also consider the MutationBatcher:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/blob/3b8ad444339a07bf5bfd024d98c615aaf688af51/google/cloud/bigtable/mutation_batcher.h#L125-L145

Comment: +1 this matches with my expectations. Will probably add a "mutation accumulator" in my client and fire all the mutations together at least once or twice per second (depending on the load). However, I would have liked an answer with more insights on the internal stuff. Already studied every piece of documentation about BigTable I could find on internet, but I still feel I don't know "the system". Yeah, I know I can trust Google...